# Java Generic Tree Comparable

Tags: java, generics, tree, comparable

So I have a final this Monday in Java and in class we went over generics and I thought it looked easy. I wanted to try it out using an example from the book. So I'm trying to make a generic tree. The thing is that My code looks almost exactly the same to examples used in class except mine won't work. I'm rather confused as to why. It tells me that I am missing an identifier in the insert method. But like I said it looks like a perfect mixture between what the professor did and the books example. I tried looking up other peoples questions on generics but I just got more confused. Is it possible for someone in simple terms(within reason) to explain to me what I am doing wrong? If your wondering on what textbook it's Java How To Program by Deitel and Deitel

```
// Tree.java
// Definition of class TreeNode and class Tree.
// class TreeNode definition
class TreeNode<E extends Comparable<TreeNode<E>>>
{

   TreeNode<E> leftNode; // left node  
   E data; // node value
   TreeNode<E> rightNode; // right node

   // constructor initializes data and makes this a leaf node
   public TreeNode( E nodeData )
   { 
      data = nodeData;              
      leftNode = rightNode = null; // node has no children
   } // end TreeNode constructor

   // locate insertion point and insert new node; ignore duplicate values
   public void <E extends Comparable<TreeNode<E>>> insert( E insertValue )
   {
      // insert in left subtree
      if ( data.compareTo(insertValue) > 0 ) 
      {
         // insert new TreeNode
         if ( leftNode == null )
            leftNode = new TreeNode<E>( insertValue );
         else // continue traversing left subtree
            leftNode.insert( insertValue ); 
      } // end if
      else if ( data.compareTo(insertValue) < 0 ) // insert in right subtree
      {
         // insert new TreeNode
         if ( rightNode == null )
            rightNode = new TreeNode<E>( insertValue );
         else // continue traversing right subtree
            rightNode.insert( insertValue ); 
      } // end else if
   } // end method insert
} // end class TreeNode

// class Tree definition
public class Tree<E>
{
   private TreeNode<E> root;

   // constructor initializes an empty Tree of integers
   public Tree() 
   { 
      root = null; 
   } // end Tree no-argument constructor

   // insert a new node in the binary search tree
   public void insertNode( E insertValue )
   {
      if ( root == null )
         root = new TreeNode<E>( insertValue ); // create the root node here
      else
         root.insert( insertValue ); // call the insert method
   } // end method insertNode

   // begin preorder traversal
   public void preorderTraversal()
   { 
      preorderHelper( root ); 
   } // end method preorderTraversal

   // recursive method to perform preorder traversal
   private void preorderHelper( TreeNode<E> node )
   {
      if ( node == null )
         return;

      System.out.printf( "%d ", node.data ); // output node data
      preorderHelper( node.leftNode );       // traverse left subtree
      preorderHelper( node.rightNode );      // traverse right subtree
   } // end method preorderHelper

   // begin inorder traversal
   public void inorderTraversal()
   { 
      inorderHelper( root ); 
   } // end method inorderTraversal

   // recursive method to perform inorder traversal
   private void inorderHelper( TreeNode<E> node )
   {
      if ( node == null )
         return;

      inorderHelper( node.leftNode );        // traverse left subtree
      System.out.printf( "%d ", node.data ); // output node data
      inorderHelper( node.rightNode );       // traverse right subtree
   } // end method inorderHelper

   // begin postorder traversal
   public void postorderTraversal()
   { 
      postorderHelper( root ); 
   } // end method postorderTraversal

   // recursive method to perform postorder traversal
   private void postorderHelper( TreeNode<E> node )
   {
      if ( node == null )
         return;

      postorderHelper( node.leftNode );      // traverse left subtree
      postorderHelper( node.rightNode );     // traverse right subtree
      System.out.printf( "%d ", node.data ); // output node data
   } // end method postorderHelper
} // end class Tree
```

This is my driver class which is a snippet the book used as an example:

```
// This program tests class Tree.
import java.util.Random;

public class TreeTest 
{
   public static void main( String args[] )
   {
      Tree tree = new Tree<E>();
      E value;
      Random randomNumber = new Random();

      System.out.println( "Inserting the following values: " );

      // insert 10 random integers from 0-99 in tree 
      for ( int i = 1; i <= 10; i++ ) 
      {
         value = randomNumber.nextInt( 100 );
         System.out.print( value + " " );
         tree.insertNode( value );
      } // end for

      System.out.println ( "\n\nPreorder traversal" );
      tree.preorderTraversal(); // perform preorder traversal of tree

      System.out.println ( "\n\nInorder traversal" );
      tree.inorderTraversal(); // perform inorder traversal of tree

      System.out.println ( "\n\nPostorder traversal" );
      tree.postorderTraversal(); // perform postorder traversal of tree
      System.out.println();
   } // end main
} // end class TreeTest
```

Comment: Did you try not using `E` in main() ? Like using `Integer`instead?

Comment: When you instantiate `Tree` you need to tell it what type `E` will be.

Comment: Oops! Raw type: `Tree tree = new Tree<E>();`. Try `Tree<E> tree = new Tree<E>();`

Answer (score 1):

There are few notable errors in your implementation.

First the generic type definition of your `TreeNode` and `Tree` classes seems erroneous. The `TreeNode` have of type `E` and `E` should be comparable (i.e Implements the `Comparable<E>` interface.

Hence I think you should define your `TreeNode` and `Tree` class as follows.

```
class TreeNode<E extends Comparable<E>> {
    //other code
}

public class Tree<E extends Comparable<E>> {
    //other code
}
```

Then, when you are using the `Tree` you should specify the actual generic type.

As example you can use your tree as follows.

```
Tree tree = new Tree<Integer>();
tree.insertNode(100);
tree.insertNode(200);
tree.insertNode(150);
tree.preorderTraversal();
```

Answer (score 0):

The following line is wrong

```
public void <E extends Comparable<TreeNode<E>>> insert( E insertValue )
```

it should be

```
public <E extends Comparable<TreeNode<E>>> void insert( E insertValue )
```

instead, but this won't solve all your problems. The correct TreeNode class should look like this

```
class TreeNode<E extends Comparable<E>> {

    TreeNode<E> leftNode; // left node
    E data; // node value
    TreeNode<E> rightNode; // right node

    // constructor initializes data and makes this a leaf node
    public TreeNode(E nodeData) {
        data = nodeData;
        leftNode = rightNode = null; // node has no children
    } // end TreeNode constructor

    // locate insertion point and insert new node; ignore duplicate values
    public void insert(E insertValue) {
        // insert in left subtree
        if (data.compareTo(insertValue) > 0) {
            // insert new TreeNode
            if (leftNode == null)
                leftNode = new TreeNode<E>(insertValue);
            else // continue traversing left subtree
                leftNode.insert(insertValue);
        } // end if
        else if (data.compareTo(insertValue) < 0) // insert in right subtree
        {
            // insert new TreeNode
            if (rightNode == null)
                rightNode = new TreeNode<E>(insertValue);
            else // continue traversing right subtree
                rightNode.insert(insertValue);
        } // end else if
    } // end method insert
} // end class TreeNode
```

You also need to change the class definition for Tree to

```
public class Tree<E extends Comparable<E>> {
```

Answer (score 0):

The main error is:

```
public void <E extends Comparable<TreeNode<E>>> insert( E insertValue )
```

which defines a new generic parameter E for the method only. It should be solely:

```
public void insert( E insertValue )
```

Then:

```
  Tree<Integer> tree = new Tree<>();
```

providing an actual generic type argument to Tree.

---

***BTW*** A bit shorter (less `new`s) would be:

Tree:

```
public void insertNode( E insertValue )
{
    root = insert( root, insertValue );
}
```

TreeNode:

```
public static TreeNode<E> insert( TreeNode<E> node, E insertValue )
{
    if (node == null)
    {
        return new TreeNode<E>( insertValue );
    }
    if ( data.compareTo(insertValue) > 0 ) 
    {
        node.leftNode = insert( node.leftNode, insertValue ); 
    }
    else if ( data.compareTo(insertValue) < 0 )
    {
        node.rightNode = insert( node.rightNode, insertValue );
    }
    return node;
}
```